# Why auto_ptr initialization using the assignment syntax is not allowed

Tags: c++, initialization, auto-ptr

I was reading through this book
[C++ standard library book](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/)

And here is the part i can not understand:

> Note that class auto_ptr<> does not allow you to initialize an object with an ordinary pointer by
>   using the assignment syntax.

```
std::auto_ptr<ClassA> ptr1(new ClassA); //ok
std::auto_ptr<ClassA> ptr2 = new ClassA; //error
```

I don't understand why it is not allowed. What kind of pitfalls they were trying to avoid by not allowing initialization with assignment syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that the assignment syntax cannot be used to initialize an `auto_ptr` from a raw pointer is a side effect of the constructor which takes a raw pointer being marked explicit. And the usual reason to mark a constructor as explicit is to prevent things like this:

```
void take_ownership(std::auto_ptr<ClassA> ptr) {
    // the pointer is deleted when this function ends
}

void foo() {
    ClassA obj;
    take_ownership(&obj); // oops, delete will be called on a pointer to
                          // an object which was not allocated with new
}
```

The call to the `take_ownership` function is an error there, because of the explicit classifier on the `std::auto_ptr` constructor. Instead, you have to deliberately construct an `auto_ptr` and pass that to the function.

```
void foo() {
    std::auto_ptr<ClassA> ptr(new ClassA);
    take_ownership(ptr); // okay
}
```

Of course this is not completely impervious to abuse (you can still pass a non-newed object to the constructor of `auto_ptr`), it is at least easier to spot when an abuse is taking place.

By the way, `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated. It is a very broken class (due to limitations in the language at the time it was introduced). Use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. I don't understand why it is not allowed.

At first direct initialization and copy initialization are not the same thing.

> ```
> std::auto_ptr<ClassA> ptr1(new ClassA); //ok
> ```

This is [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

> ```
> std::auto_ptr<ClassA> ptr2 = new ClassA; //error
> ```

This is [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization#Notes).

> Copy-initialization is less permissive than direct-initialization: explicit constructors are not converting constructors and are not considered for copy-initialization.

So if you want to initialize `std::auto_ptr` with raw pointer via copy initialization, converting constructor will be needed, but `std::auto_ptr` doesn't have it.

`std::auto_ptr`'s [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr/auto_ptr) taking one raw pointer as parameter is `explicit`, implicit conversion is prohibited.

> 2. What kind of pitfalls they were trying to avoid by not allowing initialization with assignment syntax

Consider about the following code if implicit conversion is allowed:

```
void f1(ClassA* p) { ... }
void f2(std::auto_ptr<ClassA> p) { ... }
...
ClassA* p = new ClassA;
f2(p);           // call the wrong function, ownership is transfered to auto_ptr implicitly
p->something(); // UB, p has been deleted
delete p;       // UB
```

Comment: Note that, for your example, even if `p` was declared as a properly initialized `auto_ptr`, and then passed to `f` as `f(p)` (which would compile), the next line `p->something()` would still be UB, because `auto_ptr` is a broken class.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It's right. I suppose the writer will realize it if he declare `p` as `auto_ptr` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how `std::auto_ptr` defined:

```
template< class T > class auto_ptr;
template<> class auto_ptr<void>;
```

Hence `auto_ptr` is a class type. Let's see its constructors:

```
explicit auto_ptr( X* p = 0 );
auto_ptr( auto_ptr& r );
template< class Y >
auto_ptr( auto_ptr<Y>& r );
template< class Y >
auto_ptr( auto_ptr_ref<Y> m );
```

**Consider the first constructor**. we can use a pointer to `X` type object as parameter to call this constructor:

```
std::auto_ptr<X> ptr1(new X); //ok
```

In the meanwhile, **this first constructor is `explicit`**, hence we cannot use a pointer to `X` type object implicitly to transform to `auto_ptr<X>`. In other words, we cannot initialize directly it via a pointer to `X` type object.

```
    std::auto_ptr<X> ptr1 = new X; //error; cannot implicitly transform
```

Comment: This explains *how* assignment is disallowed, but it doesn't explain *why*.